# Element opacity stuck because of psuedoelement

Tags: html, css, web, button, opacity

I'm trying to build a "block" on a website that contains a background image with lowered opacity, some text with regular opacity and a button with regular opacity

Currently, I'm getting the background image and text to work, but the button is stuck on the image's opacity (blends in with the background).

Here is the html:

```css
h1,p {
  text-align: center;
  position:relative;
  top:-70px;
  position: relative;
  color: navy;

}


.box1 {
  width: 97.5%;
  background-color: white;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 200px;
  padding-bottom: 200px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-right: 1.25%;
  margin-left: 1.25%;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);

}

.box1::before {
  content: "";
  background-image: url(/static/background.jpeg);
  background-size: contain;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.click {
  color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19)
}
```

```html
<div class="box1">
    <h1>Our Mission</h1>
    <p>THe organization plans to complete tasks x, y, z</p>
    <button class="click">Learn More</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `position: relative` to your `.click` class.

Side note: You have a duplicate `position: relative` in your `h1, p` selector.